# Node.js Clustering - Is there automatically a Load Balancer in place?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have a 4 core CPU with 8 logical processors, which in this code creates 8 workers and 1 master process. When a `socket` connection is formed, it tends to connect to the last worker, `CPU 8`. Does using this method automatically add a `Load Balancer`, or would I need to add it in? Is there a way to test if the `Load Balancer` is working? I've tried to add 100s of clients, but they all connect to `CPU 8` - not sure if it could be because there is barely any process handling in this instance

Simple Node.js Clustering

```
const os = require('os'),
  cluster = require('cluster'),
  cores = os.cpus();
var clusterCount = 0;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  // Fork workers
  for (let i = 0; i < cores.length; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
}
else {
  const http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    process = require('process');;

  var cpu = cores[clusterCount];
  var app = express();
  var port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8080;
  var server = app.listen(port);
  var io = socketio(server);

  io.adapter(socketioRedis({ host: config.redis_host, port: config.redis_port }));

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected to worker ${process.pid}`);
  });

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started on port: ${port} | ${cpu.model}`);
  clusterCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a couple of points. https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

> Does using this method automatically add a Load Balancer?

The master will handle the load balancing.

```
sure if it could be because there is barely any process handling in this instance
```

It might be that CPU 8 is not that busy and can still handle the load. There are two strategies which also depend on the OS you are using.

Comment: Figured as much. Is there a way you can suggest to test out the functionality of the `Load Balancing`?

Comment: @VardanBetikyan As you'd expect: by either adding load to the process itself, or by swarming more clients.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I just added a pointless `for` loop and it started throwing the clients in different workers. Appreciate it guys, thanks!